# Gamma distribution and pdf

Tags: statistics

Let $X \sim \mathsf{Gamma}(2,3)$ and $Y = 2X.$
Find the pdf of $Y$ at $y=13.5.$

Attempt: $f_X(x)= 2*[1/9*\Gamma(2)]*x*e^{-x/3}.$
Do I have to integrate now?

Comment: I don't understand. You want the probability that  $Y=13.5$? This is surely $0$ since this is a continuous distribution.

Comment: That's what confuses me. Is the question worded incorrectly? Or is it a trick question? The instructions say that my answer needs to have 4 decimal places.

Comment: Well, I would start by finding the pdf of $Y $. Do you know the method of CDF, MGF or transformation?

Comment: I'm not sure how to find the pdf of Y.

Comment: No need to hypothetize a "trick question": in full generality, $$f_{2X}(y)=\frac12\,f_X\left(\frac{y}2\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

$X\sim \text{Gamma}(2,3)\implies f_X(x)=\frac{1}{9\Gamma(2)}xe^{-x/3}$ for $x>0$. The method of CDF yields (for $y>0$):
$$\begin{align}F_Y(y)&=P(Y\leq y)\\&=P\left(X\leq\frac{y}{2}\right)\\&=\int_0^{y/2}\frac{1}{9}xe^{-x/3}dx\\&=\frac{-1}{3}\left[(x+3)e^{-x/3}\right]^{y/2}_0\\&=1-\frac{y+6}{6}e^{-y/6}\end{align}$$
Using the fact that $f_Y(y)=\frac{d}{dy}F_Y(y)$, we see that:
$$f_Y(y)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{36}ye^{-y/6}\qquad x>0\\0\qquad\qquad\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
Thus, $Y\sim\text{Gamma}(2,6)$. Hope this helps.

Comment: Why go through PDF$\to$CDF$\to$CDF$\to$PDF when PDF$\to$PDF is elementary?

Comment: @Did I figured the CDF method provides more information than the transformation method, both of which are unknown to the OP apparently.

Comment: "more information" How?

Comment: @Did it provides the CDF function of $Y$.

Comment: Which is not needed for the PDF... Providing the direct way (possibly completed, if really one insists, by the détour in your answer) would seem mandatory in such situations, no?

Comment: @Did I wouldn't say it is mandatory to use the more direct method, although it may be easier. I simply just offer a solution using the CDF method which yields the distribution of $Y $, as well as provides the CDF function which may be needed to answer other questions.

Comment: "Providing" (not "using") the direct method seems mandatory, yes.

Comment: @Did I would not say it is "mandatory" to provide such a solution.

Comment: And this opinion indicates a peculiar approach to pedagogy...

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

Suppose $X $~ Gamma(2,3).  Then the moment generating function for $X$ is:

$$f(t) = E(e^{tX}) = (1-\theta t)^{-k} = (1-3t)^{-2}$$

Also, the moment generating function for $2X$ is: $$E(e^{t2X}) = E(e^{(2t)X}) = f(2t) = (1-3(2t))^{-2}$$

So we see that $2X$ has moment generating function $(1 - 6t)^{-2}$, so that $2X$ ~ Gamma(2,6).